# Woocommerce (shop) header in product-archives.php file

Tags: php, wordpress, header, woocommerce

I read that it is possible to place alternative header into woocommerce pages using `get_header('shop');` in product-archives.php template in my custom theme. In order to make it work I need to make copy of header.php file and rename it to header-shop.php. It should be also located in same folder as header.php file.
Unfortunately I can't get this to work.
Anything I am missing if somebody notices that would be great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a work around.

1. Just make a copy of *header.php* in your current theme with the same name (i.e. *header.php*).
2. Create another copy of the *header.php* with you desired name(i.e. *header-shop.php*).
3. Now you just need to add a custom code in *header.php* at the starting lines to check that whether its a product archive page(using this function http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive), if yes then include the *header-shop.php* else show the below default code of the file itself.

An Example Snippet:

```
if ( is_post_type_archive('product')) {
     // Load header-shop.php
}else{
     // continue with default code
}
```

Comment: This is great - it seems to work for my main shop page, but none of the "product-category" or "product" pages beneath this - e.g. works for domain/shop, but not for domain/product-category/cat1 or domain/product/item

Answer (score 0):

Even you can load header-shop.php with the PHP function include_once()

```
    if ( is_post_type_archive('product')) {
     include_once 'header-shop.php'; 
    }
```